# How to return 1 result Dynamic Page Generation in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, dynamic

I need to put a parameter in here so that only ONE verse will show per page. But, I don't know what to put or where to put it. I hope I'm showing the right section of code.

My book and chapter lists are loading fine, but when the chapter copy is displayed, all of my verses are showing on one page.

```
// append verses as paragraphs
var chapterHTML = '';
$( verseNodeName , chapter).each(function(i) {
   var vers = $(this);
   chapterHTML += '<p><sup>'+ (i+1) +'</sup> '+ vers.text() +'</p>'
 });

// Get the empty page we are going to insert our content into.
var $page = $('#chapter');

// Get the header for the page to set it
$header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" );
$header.find( "h1" ).html( book.bname +' '+ chapterNum );

// Get the content element for the page to set it
$content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" );
$content.html(chapterHTML);
```

I hope somebody can help me...Here's where I got the demo/code, if anybody can help: http://www.moretechtips.net/2012/07/dynamic-page-generation-in-jquery.html